# .net core to sqlserverce issue

Tags: .net-core, sql-server-ce

I am trying to connect to a SQL Server CE (.sdf) file using the .Net Core console. I keep on getting the error below whereas the same code is working properly in the .Net Framework.

Can anyone suggest to me what the issue is?

> The type initializer for 'System.Data.SqlServerCe.KillBitHelper' threw
>   an exception. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load
>   file or assembly 'System.Security.Permissions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible and not supported, System.Data.SqlServerCe requires the full .NET Framework and Windows.

**UPDATE** It is actually possible (on Windows only) with .NET Core 3.x - see https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/33897#issuecomment-536269132